# Upload de Imagem em Formato Blob

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Bom dia!

Estou tentando enviar dados binários do Blob por Ajax para fazer o upload via PHP.

index.html:

```
document.getElementById("btnSave").addEventListener("click", event => {
            canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
                var reader = new FileReader();
                var obBlob = "";
                reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
                reader.onload = function () {
                    console.log(reader.result)//retorna o binário
                    $.ajax({
                        url : "upload.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {obBlob: reader.result},
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        dataType:"text/plain",
                        success: function(resultado) {
                          console.log(resultado);
                        },
                        error: function(resultado) {
                            console.log(resultado);
                        }

                    });
                }//fim do reader
            });
        });
```

upload.php

```
$obBlob = !empty($_REQUEST["obBlob"])? $_REQUEST["obBlob"]: die("Nenhuma imgagem encontrada");
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "fotos";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO fotos (foto) VALUES ($obBlob)";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    mysqli_close($conn);
    echo $conn->error;
}else{
    mysqli_close($conn);
    die("Error:".$conn->error);
}
```

O log do console:

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …} abort : ƒ (e) always : ƒ () catch : ƒ (e) done : ƒ () fail : ƒ () getAllResponseHeaders : ƒ () getResponseHeader : ƒ (e) overrideMimeType : ƒ (e) pipe : ƒ () progress : ƒ () promise : ƒ (e) readyState : 4 responseText : "Nenhuma imgagem encontrada" setRequestHeader : ƒ (e,t) state : ƒ () status : 200 statusCode : ƒ (e) statusText : "OK" then : ƒ (t,r,i)
__proto__ : Object
```

detalhe do retorno do upload.php:

> responseText : "Nenhuma imgagem encontrada"

tentei passar o blob, não chega nada.... inclusive eu coloquei o dataType no Ajax pois caso contrario ele não consegue nem encontrar o índice no $_REQUEST. Entretanto o $_REQUEST está chegando vazio! tentei passar o binário, também chega vazio...  Ao menos é o que me parece!

Sei que existem várias resoluções prontas, mas como estou aprendendo, eu gostaria de entender os motivos... desde já agradeço a ajuda!

está dando erro, e no console está retornando os binários e o seguinte erro:

> responseText : "
> ↵**Notice**:  Undefined index: obBlob in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\WEBCAM\upload.php** on line **2**

Tentei passar por XMLHTTPRequest() também da seguinte forma:

```
document.getElementById("btnSave").addEventListener("click", event => {
   canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
      var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
      oReq.open("POST","upload.php", true);
      oReq.send(blob);
   });
});
```

Galera... ainda não consegui enviar... tentei desta outra forma:

```
document.getElementById("btnSave").addEventListener("click", event => {
                canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
                                var json = JSON.stringify(blob);
                                console.log(json);
                                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                                xhr.open("POST", 'upload.php', true);
                                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
                                xhr.send(json);
                });
            });
```

neste caso, a variavel json mostra um objeto vazio!

de qualquer forma, minha melhor opção foi o ajax, pois o erro neste caso está vindo do upload.php que esta retornando OK, mas com a mensagem de "imagem não encontrada".

Mas como eu disse no inicio deste post, sou newbe em javascript... nao sei como faço pra receber o erro neste ultimo caso, então fico sem resposta no console... se alguém puder me dar algumas dicas eu fico muito grato!

Valeuu!!

Comment: Qual erro que acusa?

Comment: não acusa! simplesmente não acontece nada! inclusive eu coloquei um return true no upload.php no inicio do código pra ver se executaria o alert de sucesso do $.post mas nada aconteceu tbm!

Comment: document.getElementById("btnSave").addEventListener("click", event => {
    canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
        $.post('upload.php',{blob}, function(){
            alert("Foto salva com sucesso!");
        });
    });
}).fail(function(){
 alert( "error" );
});

Comment: coloca asism o js para ver se o alert de erro aparece e verifica tambem o console (F12 na maioria dos navegadores)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at e (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
    at Wc (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
    at Wc (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
    at Function.n.param (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
    at Function.n.(/webcam/anonymous function) [as post] (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4:22698)
    at (index):62

axo que nao estou incluindo o JQuery direito!

Answer (score 1):

Tenta fazer assim:

```
document.getElementById("btnSave").addEventListener("click", event => {
    canvas.toBlob(function(blob){        
        $.ajax({
            url : "upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: blob,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function() {
              alert("funcionou!");
            },    
            error: function() {
              alert("não funcionou!");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: com ajax ele entrou no sucesso... só nao salvou no bd, mas deve ser alguma configuração aqui...Valeu mesmo... por que será que com o JQuery nao deu certo?

Comment: Faltava o contentType e o processData no `$.post`, pelo menos foi o que eu entendi

Comment: Bom dia... estou com dificuldade de passar os dados binários... quando tento pegar o $_POST, não chega nada.... abro outro tópico ou edito este? alterei um pouco o código!

Comment: só editar esse aqui mesmo

Comment: alterei meu código pra transformar o objeto blob em binário, mas ainda não consegui passar pro upload.php =//